# How to concat rows in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, database

I`m running this query below:

```
SELECT a.id as id_order, b.id as id_service,
   d.nome as service_name, 
   c.dente as tooth,
   (SELECT count(c.dente) 
    FROM labpedidoservicodente c 
    WHERE b.id = c.idLabPedidoServico) AS total,
    e.valorServico as cost
FROM   labpedido a 
   INNER JOIN labpedidoservico b 
           ON a.id = b.idLabPedido 
   INNER JOIN labpedidoservicodente c 
           ON a.id = c.idLabPedido 
   INNER JOIN labservico d 
           ON b.idLabServico = d.id 
   INNER JOIN labservicovalor e
           ON b.idLabServico = e.idLabServico
WHERE  a.id = '914'
```

My result comes this way:

```
order_id  service_id  service_name     tooth   total   cost
914          640      SERVICE NAME 1     11      3    80.00
914          640      SERVICE NAME 1     21      3    80.00
914          640      SERVICE NAME 1     38      3    80.00
914          641      SERVICE NAME 2     11      3    84.80
914          641      SERVICE NAME 2     21      3    84.80
914          641      SERVICE NAME 2     38      3    84.80
```

My desired output should be like this:

```
order_id  service_id  service_name     tooth   total   cost
914          640      SERVICE NAME 1    11-21    2    80.00
914          641      SERVICE NAME 2     38      1    84.60
```

The problem is that I need to concat these rows in the column "tooth" inside their respective "service_id", have tried everything but no sucess, also the total

Answer (score 0):

Replace `c.dente` with `GROUP_CONCAT(c.dente SEPARATOR ' - ')` and add `GROUP BY service_id` below.

Comment: That works with the concat part but still, it mixes the tooth from service name 1 and service name 2 in the same row when it should be splitted.

Comment: I did a subquery inside you recommendation and it worked out:

(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.dente SEPARATOR ' - ') from labpedidoservicodente c where b.id = c.idLabPedidoServico) as tooth... it`s not concat and splited as it`s supposed to be. Thanks!